# Is it good idea to have multiple ViewModel.observe in a single Activity?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, observers

I have an activity that I named it MainActivity. For this activity I have created a ViewModel that its name is MainViewModel.
In this activity I have 3 network calling and I have created 3 observers for them in MainViewModel. First I call first request, when this request is successful I'll call second request and when this is successful too I'll call third request.

My code is something look likes this:

```
...
private MainViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    viewModel.doRequestOne();

    viewModel.requestOne.observe(this, result -> {
       // check if it is success, then call doRequestTwo()
       viewModel.doRequestTwo();
    });

    viewModel.requestTwo.observe(this, result -> {
       // check if it is success then call doRequestThree()
       viewModel.doRequestThree();
    });;

    viewModel.requestThree.observe(this, result -> {
       // Success
    });

}
```

Now I wanna know is there any better way for doing this approach? Because I have to do this scenario in several activities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to relay on **ViewModel architecture**, is better to have everything regarding requests, network and data things in view models. So all this logic from your example should be in **viewModel**. You should just observe final result, except if you want to show on UI also partial results.

Comment: thanks for your replaying. I don't know how I should observer observers in a ViewModel, Could you please explain more or suggest me an article or link? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sure, check here how it should be: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide Check how to deal with LiveData<> and observing in activity..